# Tomcat accepting HTTP from Apache, while Apache accepting HTTPS from user, does tomcat need to be HTTPS enabled too?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, http, https

My application serves html pages through Apache server to user and it ssl-https enabled. These pages makes ajax request to my backend application running on tomcat container. Tomcat is not ssl enabled yet, so ajax request is being sent over http. This is creating error in user's browser that mixed content is being requested hence request is being blocked.

What do I do here? 
Enable tomcat with ssl?
Or is there a way to send request from Apache to Tomcat without using HTTP or HTTPS as both are running on same virtual machine?

Comment: **All** of the communication between the browser and your server needs to be SSL. Period. Either SSL-enable tomcat or proxy requests to it through your SSL-enabled Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a reverse proxy in the same https vhost and rewrite the path, so /app/ goes to tomcat, then update your code.

Answer (score -1):

For you error, I don't think the http or https is the issue.

Check the logs to know more.
tomcat and apache are able to talk http, with proxypass or ajp13/ajp14 connectors.